# Trouble with a contact form, sending emails using Gmail, was working great now I've added new html files to another app it's stopped working

Tags: javascript, django, email, gmail

I had my emails generating in the terminal in development and to my Gmail in production.

All working very well. Once I done a bit more code which involved static sites and a modal on another app in my django project.

It now doesn't work. If I roll back my project it works again. So it's something I've done, however, I haven't changed anything on my contact app.

Can anyone suggest anything please

https://github.com/StaceyRb89/transcribe.git

I removed the custom javascript, and bootstrap javascript from the base.html hoping it could have been that,  but it didn't make a difference, so the home page burger button doesn't work as well as it should. But it was to try it out.

I have messed around with settings. I even copied the older commit directly to it which was exactly the same bar the two src js files,

I don't know what else to do. I have searched and should probably mention I've only been coding for 5 months.

Thank you